# たたく versus ぶつ in a JLPT question

Tags: word-choice, jlpt

In my JLPT practise book, there is a section demonstrating the difference between `なぐる`, `たたく`, `打{う}つ`, and `ぶつ`. If I understand them, they are all variants of "hit", with subtle nuances to differentiate them.

I have this example explaining the use of `ぶつ`:

> いたずらをした子供{こども}は、母親{ははおや}にお尻{しり}をぶたれた。

And then I have this question:

> なまけ者{もの}の弟{おとうと}は人{ひと}から尻{しり}を_***_*__**_ないと、なかなか仕事{しごと}をしない。
>
> **A**　ぶたれ 　**B**　たたかれ 　**C**　打{う}たれ 　**D**　なぐられ

I chose **A**, which means I fell unto the usual JLPT trap where they deliberately mislead with similar contexts. D'oh!

Still, in any case, I can't see why **B** is a better answer.　In fact, the subtleties of difference make me unsure why any of them are not appropriate.

What makes **B** the right answer, and the rest wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to specify **JLPT(N1)** in your titles.  In fact, it's potentially turning away viewers and additional responses from people who aren't at that level.

Comment: @istrasci: Okay, I can agree to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **尻をぶつ**:

  > Means to spank someone as punishment for something which has been done (in the first case because of naughtiness.)
- **尻をたたく**:

  > Means to give someone a good hiding without those connotations (in that case because of laziness.)
- **打つ**:

  > Doesn't work because `ぶつ` is used for people and `打つ` for inanimate things.
- **殴る**:

  > Doesn't work because it's more for violently hitting/continuous beating of someone with a stick/fist etc.

`なまけ者` means "lazy person" and `なかなか仕事をしない` means "the (younger brother) stays lazy" in this context I believe, so the sentence would translate to "unless the lazy younger brother is given a good hiding, he stays lazy."

Comment: `Means to give someone a **good hiding**`. That seems a bit awkward. Is this UK English for spanking?

Comment: @dotnetN00b Very late reply but yes, I believe it is. My parents used to threaten to give me a 'good 'idin' if I kept misbehaving (and never made good on these threats)

Answer (score 12):

尻をたたく is an idiom, sort of like English "kick in the pants". Consider:

> My lazy little brother never does any work until someone gives him a good kick in the pants.

You wouldn't interpret this as *literal* brutality, just forceful reminding/urging. Same goes for 尻をたたく, at least in this case, and you can tell because of context: it just seems really unlikely that modern-day training materials for a nice upper-middle-class test like JLPT(N1) would present stories of someone's brother getting *literally* beaten by unnamed third parties simply for being lazy.

I also think that when talking about someone *else's* butt in the context of literal butt-spanking (i.e. not using a set idiom like 尻をたたく) you would tend to use お尻, not just 尻.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this was a very helpful answer. The only reason I marked @cypher's answer as the correct one instead was because the way he broke down the different meanings helped me more in the context of answering a JLPT question.

Comment: Great answer Matt. Your answer had a lot of aspects which I just didn't see and made me realize mistakes in my own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @DaveMG (no hard feelings, of course!), and comment, cypher. Glad I was able to help out.